# Assemble Web API + Web frontend in the same Visual Studio solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am learning ASP.Net MVC & Web APIs.

For this moment, I have 2 solutions:

- Solution A is the Web solution (frontend)
- Solution B is a Web API Project

**For testing**: I start solutions A & B (http://localhost/46433 + http://localhost/3400). I successfully can hit api controller in solution B from solution A.

As you can see, each solution live on its own (2 different URLs).

I would like to know if this is possible to assemble everything inside only one solution (with the Web frontend as the default startup project). In this scenario, how is it possible to have the Web API Project running ?

What I would like to achieve:

[image]

For me it is easier to have everything inside only one solution.

Comment: It is possible to do so, but the architecture would differ a bit according to the technologies you would use. What are you using for your front end application?

Comment: Just one note more, you can also debug multi instances in one solution explorer without doing any config just by right clicking on project `Debug-> Start new Instance` but by this you should do this one by one otherwise you can set them in `Solution Properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio:

1- On the File menu, click `New` and then click `New Project`.

2- In the left pane, select `Installed`, select `Other Project` Types, and then select 
`Visual Studio Solutions` from the expanded list.

3- In the middle pane, select `Blank Solution`.

4- Set the Name and `Location` values for your solution, then click OK.

5- Your empty solution will be created, Then move your projects folder into defined `Location` in step 4 then in `Solution Explorer` Right click on the solution name you have created in step 4 then `Add Existing` project one by one from the location defined is step 4 too.

For multiple startup project do below steps:
1- In Solution Explorer, select the solution (the top node).

2- Choose the solution node's context (right-click) menu and then choose Properties. The Solution Property Pages dialog box appears.

3- Expand the Common Properties node, and choose Startup Project.

4- Choose the Multiple Startup Projects option and set the appropriate actions.

[Reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2017)

Comment: What you suggest is simply creating a new solution. It does not respond to my question: I would like to know if this is possible to assemble everything inside only one solution (with the Web frontend as the default startup project). In this scenario, how is it possible to have the Web API Project running ?

Comment: In step 5 you have to add `.csproj` file to your empty solution such as `DWx.Webb.csproj` file.

Comment: You want to debug all the projects in solution together in one shoot ?

Comment: So you suggest to create 1 solution with 2 projects inside. Okay but how is it possible to keep every 2 projects having its own live (URL) ?

Comment: Right click on your project and go to `Propeties`>`Web` and set you different url in `Project Url` box.

Comment: To debug them together you can copy `SolutionA` `dll` and `pdb` files into `bin` folder of `SolutionB` and vice versa, or if api is needs in front end add api reference into front end solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advises.